# Error: First argument should be an array in

Tags: php

I have this code and no code before it that refers to any variables seen below. Yet I still can't find why I'm getting the error: "First argument should be an array in..."

```
$array = array("element here for reason");

function sortdata()
{
    $File = fopen("Names.txt", "r");

    //put each file line into an array element
    while(!feof($File))
    {
        array_push($array, fgets($File));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line number is the error message referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$array` is out of scope to the function.  You can bring it into scope using `global`.

```
$array = ..;
function sortdata() {
    global $array;
    ...
}
sortdata();
```

Alternatively, you can pass it by reference into the function.

```
$array = ..;
function sortdata(&$array) {
    ...
}
sortdata($array);
```

Comment: Tried and then defined $array on next line, same problem

Comment: Tried which variation? Assuming `$array` is declared at the script-output level, you can bring it into the function's context with that global statement.  If you use the code from this answer correctly, there will be no issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to first initialize the array and bring the array within the scope of the function like so:

```
$array = array();
array_push($array, "element here for reason");

function sortdata()
{
    global $array;

    $File = fopen("Names.txt", "r");

    //put each file line into an array element
    while(!feof($File))
    {
        array_push($array, fgets($File));
    }
}
```

Comment: `$array` is still out of scope within the function.

Comment: At this point, it's basically a less-explaining variation of my answer.

Comment: @Vulcan So I should then rollback your suggestion to unimprove my answer?

Comment: No need to, but I should undownvote your answer as it's now a correct answer.  Do you mind making a small edit so I can change my vote?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code is that you are not passing the $array variable into the function. Aside from that, it would be more efficient to use the shortcut way to add an item to the array instead of calling array_push since it eliminates the overhead of calling a function.

```
$array = array("element here for reason");

function sortdata($array)
{
    $File = fopen("Names.txt", "r");

    //put each file line into an array element
    while(!feof($File))
    {
        $array[] = fgets($File);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: The `$array` passed as a parameter won't actually have values pushed into it unless you pass it by reference.

Comment: That's not true. The $array variable being passed is indeed being passed by value. However, that does not change the fact that it is an array variable. The $array[] line will append data to the array. If you use the OUTPUT of the function, $array = sortdata($array);, then you will get the updated $array. However, if you do not store the output then you are correct, the value of $array will not change.

Comment: I was simply noting it for the OP's sake, because his/her original code suggests that the function has no return value.  I assume(d) that OP's original code does not store the output into the variable as is, so I noted that.

Answer (score 0):

You use variable $array inside function body. In this case this is local variable and it automatically sets to string.

For work with your global variable $array you should use instruction **global** in your function.

```
function sortdata() {
global $array;
/* there your code for work with $array */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This give you backward compatibility

function sortdata(array $array = array())
{
    $File = fopen("Names.txt", "r");

    while(!feof($File))
    {
      array_push($array, fgets($File));
    }


    return $array;
}
```